# A better way to execute a streaming library

Tags: javascript, node.js, library

I am building a wrapper around the `sharp` image library.

The usage revolves around chaining tasks. But I wish to execute it by just passing in a config.

An example of what I am currently doing:

```
var execute = function ( obj, task ) {

    var methodName = task[0];
    var passedValue = task[1];

    return obj[ methodName ]( passedValue );
};
```

The complete code is found here : [sharp-brunch](https://github.com/privatmamtora/sharp-brunch/blob/78a9941d6bbb783625e152b2d00a4c3e20404d41/lib/index.js#L189-L199)

Is there a simpler way to do this?

**Edit:**
I am looking for a neater/ more appropriate way to do this.
The current method works, but I was hoping someone would tell me a way to write it better.

Tool is to be used by developers. If they configure it wrong it will crash. It will throw errors and complain.

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid that hypothetical, pseudo or otherwise obfuscated code is off-topic for Code Review. If it's only 70 lines of code, please feel free to post it all in the question itself.

Comment: @Zak the code presented is the actual code from the link.. If you want to close this it might be more appropriate to close as "unclear what you're asking" which is what I'm voting for now

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! To make life easier for reviewers, please add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about what your code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. See also [this meta question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1226/code-should-include-a-description-of-what-the-code-does)

Answer (score 2):

Your validation is scaringly non-existing!

You currently don't even check if `obj` has the method `methodName`. You don't check if `obj` is an object!

Here's how I would do that:

```
var tmp = new Object(obj);

if(!tmp.hasOwnProperty(task[0]))
{
    throw new TypeError('First arguments must be an object');
}
```

But still you don't verify if it is a function or not.

Here's how I would do that bit:

```
if(!(tmp[task[0]] instanceof Function))
{
    throw new TypeError('The object\'s property "' + task[0] + '" ins\'t a function');
}
```

But even then, you don't verify if `task` is an array or not.

Here's how you can do that:

```
if(!(task[0] instanceof Array))
{
    throw new TypeError('The 2nd argument must be an array');
}
```

---

And you have another problem: You throw away all the other arguments. If you want a function to accept 2 arguments, you're throwing it away.

This is how I would write that bit:

```
var method = task.unshift(); //removes the 1st elements and returns

...

return tmp[method].apply(tmp, task);
```

This has the side-effect of changing the array! To combat this, you can make a shallow copy using the `.slice()` method.

---

**Final code:**

I have 2 proposals, both work the same but look a bit different.

**Version 1:**

```
var execute = function(obj, task) {
    if(!(task[0] instanceof Array))
    {
        throw new TypeError('The 2nd argument must be an array');
    }

    var tmp = new Object(obj);
    var method = task[0];

    if(!tmp.hasOwnProperty(method))
    {
        throw new TypeError('First arguments must be an object');
    }

    if(!(tmp[method] instanceof Function))
    {
        throw new TypeError('The object\'s property "' + method + '" ins\'t a function');
    }

    return tmp[method].apply(tmp, task.slice(1));

}
```

**Version 2:**

```
var execute = function(obj, task) {
    if(!(task[0] instanceof Array))
    {
        throw new TypeError('The 2nd argument must be an array');
    }

    var tmp = new Object(obj);
    var args = task.slice(); //shallow copy
    var method = args.unshift();

    if(!tmp.hasOwnProperty(method))
    {
        throw new TypeError('First arguments must be an object');
    }

    if(!(tmp[method] instanceof Function))
    {
        throw new TypeError('The object\'s property "' + method + '" ins\'t a function');
    }

    return tmp[method].apply(tmp, task);

}
```

They don't vary much, and their differences aren't that big. It's up to you to decide which one you like the most.

It is easy to make a 3rd version to allow array-like objects to be passed as the 2nd parameter.

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the code you put here for review is very minimalistic. There's not much context. What you appear to have is a task which has a method name and argument, and you want to run that method on a given instance.....

While your variable names are meaningful, the variables themselves are unnecessary... especially if you use the actual invocation method name for the call.

```
var execute = function ( obj, task ) {
    return obj[task[0]](task[1]);
};
```

That whole thing begs the question as to why you need it at all.....

Instead of running, for example:

```
execute(users[i], ["setGender", "male"]);
```

why not just do:

```
users[i]["setGender"]("male");
```

Or, in a more general way:

```
obj[task[0]](task[1]);
```

because that's almost as easy as:

```
execute(obj, task);
```

Comment: Actually I want to throw it away all together. But I couldn't figure out a way to do it. which is the actual question